# PyCharm not recognising .py extension

Tags: python, pycharm

community,

I encountered the following issue. I have several classes/ files that I am editing in PyCharm. As you can see PyCharm recognises every file as a valid .py file except the **PresidentsPage**

[image: Every class except of one is shown as .py file]

The problem about that is that auto-completion and code formatting isn't working properly. I already tried to create a new file and copy and pasting the code in there. Sadly that didn't work. Maybe one of you has a smart idea :)

[image: PresidentsPage.py not being recognised as Python file]

---

[image: PlayersPage.py being recognised as Python file]

---

I also checked the extensions in the Preferences. They are perfectly fine
[image]

---

When I rename the file to something stupid like 'PjresidentsPage' it is shown as a Python file

[image]

Comment: Depending on the version. Did you try creating a python file rather than a file? Cannot recreate on my version as it is able to detect a `.py` file

Comment: yes, i tried it both. I tried creating a new Python file. After i entered the name and pressed enter the IDE again showed it to me like a regular text file

Comment: Hmm weird. Did you try changing the name?

Comment: Yep thanks to your idea :D and when i change the name to something stupid like 'PjresidentsPage' it works ... that's strange. I edited my question

Comment: It may be related to cache problems. So may be delete the files and try to delete the cache and check if there exist no file with the same name but with file format as text. Should be enough

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen this issue before, after mistakenly creating a .py module as a plain text file, PyCharm will auto-register that specific filename as a text file.

Navigate to *Settings -> Editor -> File Types*.

Under *Recognized File Types* panel, select the *Text* file type.

Under *Registered Patterns* panel, find your filename `PresidentsPage.py` and remove it from the registered patterns (by clicking the "-" icon on right). Click *Apply*.

Now recreate your file as .py file, not a plain text file.

[image: cap]